# Javascript reduce multiple objects and combine them with the same key id

Tags: javascript, object

So I have a problem here that I have a list of objects with an ID and time. So what I did here was trying to loop out each of these results and push a number based on the time that I set. It would also push 0 if the time does not equal of the hour.

```js
let formatted = [];

const results = [
  { id: 'id1', time: 4 },
  { id: 'id1', time: 5 },
  { id: 'id2', time: 1 },
  { id: 'id2', time: 15 },
  { id: 'id2', time: 12 },
  { id: 'id3', time: 6 },
  { id: 'id3', time: 8 },
];

const hours = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, ];

results.forEach((result) => {
  let hourArr = [];

  hours.forEach((hour) => {
    hourArr.push(result.time == hour ? hour : 0);
  });

  formatted.push({ id: result.id, time: hourArr });
});

console.log(formatted);
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    id: 'id1',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id1',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id2',
    time: [
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id2',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id2',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id3',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id3',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
];
```

The problem here is that every iteration of the object only inserts as a new object instead of combining the existing one.

What I want for the output:

```js
[
  {
    id: 'id1',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id2',
    time: [
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 'id3',
    time: [
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: btw, what do you with time zero? why do you have such strenge format? if really an array for times, take a boolean value or an array with only times you have.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic 'group by' on the `id` property, but instead of pushing your `time` values you can assign the index of the newly added `time` array using each objects value. (I question the value of doing this since you haven't really gained anything and are storing the same data using more space, but nevertheless...)

```js
const input = [{ id: 'id1', time: 4, }, { id: 'id1', time: 5, }, { id: 'id2', time: 1, }, { id: 'id2', time: 15, }, { id: 'id2', time: 12, }, { id: 'id3', time: 6, }, { id: 'id3', time: 8, },];

const result = input.reduce(
  (a, o) => {
    if (!a[o.id]) {
      a[o.id] = { ...o, time: Array(24).fill(0) };
      a._.push(a[o.id]);
    }
    a[o.id].time[o.time] = o.time;
    return a;
  },
  { _: [] }
)._;

console.log(result);
```

Or using `Object.values` instead of a referential accumulator

```js
const input = [{ id: 'id1', time: 4, }, { id: 'id1', time: 5, }, { id: 'id2', time: 1, }, { id: 'id2', time: 15, }, { id: 'id2', time: 12, }, { id: 'id3', time: 6, }, { id: 'id3', time: 8, },];

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce((a, o) => {
    (a[o.id] ??= { ...o, time: Array(24).fill(0) }).time[o.time] = o.time;
    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Here is the abstracted assignment logic for illustration purposes

```js
const object = { time: Array(24).fill(0) };
const time = 4;

object.time[time] = time; // a marvel of opaque variable naming

console.log(object);
// { time: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] }
```

---

The classic 'group by', simply accumulating the values into an array, would look something like the following

```js
const input = [{ id: 'id1', time: 4, }, { id: 'id1', time: 5, }, { id: 'id2', time: 1, }, { id: 'id2', time: 15, }, { id: 'id2', time: 12, }, { id: 'id3', time: 6, }, { id: 'id3', time: 8, },];

const result = Object.values(
  input.reduce(
    (a, o) => ((a[o.id] ??= { ...o, time: [] }).time.push(o.time), a),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(result);

/*
[
  { id: 'id1', time: [ 4, 5 ] },
  { id: 'id2', time: [ 1, 15, 12 ] },
  { id: 'id3', time: [ 6, 8 ] }
]
*/
```

Comment: What does the { _: [] } and the )._; after the reduce function do?

Comment: By using an initial accumulator of the shape ` { _: [] }` we can build the result array by reference during the grouping and access it after the reduce using `)._;`. This allows us to avoid calling `Object.values` on the result, but does add some complexity.

Comment: Added an example using `Object.values`